# I'm trying to connect CSS to HTML, but it's not working

Tags: html, css

I've looked for problems in both my folder and in my code, but I can't see the problem. I put my CSS and HTML in the same folder. index.html0 is the name of my folder.

my code is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text,css" href="style.css">
```

I've also tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text,css" href="index.html/style.css">
```

it still doesn't work. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

`<link href="cssFileName.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

You put a "," between text and css, it is a "/".

Comment: I need to have at least 50 reputation to made a comment, that way would be easier, but I had to made an answer. Accept the answer if you liked it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Another form of importing css is the use of
`@import "styles.css"; Using a string`
or
`@import url("styles.css"); /* Using a url */`

For further information pls refer to w3schools documentation https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_import_rule.php

But Ideally try not to use the @import method for css try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
```